# How to use conan compon with my own build system? can you give me a demo?

Tags: conan

I am new to conan, and I want to use the feature of component of conan,

I read the https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/package_information.html

but still cannot know how to use it .

likes the example:

'''

```
self.cpp_info.name = "OpenSSL"

self.cpp_info.components["crypto"].names["cmake_find_package"] = "Crypto"

self.cpp_info.components["crypto"].libs = ["libcrypto"]

self.cpp_info.components["crypto"].defines = ["DEFINE_CRYPTO=1"]

self.cpp_info.components["ssl"].names["cmake"] = "SSL"

self.cpp_info.components["ssl"].includedirs = ["include/headers_ssl"]

self.cpp_info.components["ssl"].libs = ["libssl"]

self.cpp_info.components["ssl"].requires = ["crypto"]
```

'''

why the crypto self.cpp_info.components["crypto"].names["cmake_find_package"] = "Crypto" ?

my build system is not based on CMake.

how to extract files to every component?

how to copy to local cache?
how to consume one component?

can anyone can give a demo how to create two libs and how to consume the libs

based on

https://github.com/shreyasbharath/conan-package-binary-example

https://github.com/shreyasbharath/conan-package-binary-consume-example

Thanks you very much !

Comment: Why don't you start from the basic template with ``conan new hello/0.1 --template=cmake_lib`` and start moving from there? It seems your recipes do not build in the recipe but outside, which is usually more complicated, why not use the build() method?

Comment: conan new hello/0.1 --template=cmake_lib cannot help me to understand the concept of component.  i have a big repository have lots of libraries.  one option is to create a recipe for every library.  but want to try the component.    https://github.com/shreyasbharath/conan-package-binary-example  is easy to understand，contain two a file。 how to make two  file to two  components and how to consume one library?

Comment: @drodri : can you kindly give a demo based on cmake?

Comment: Maybe you can have a look to some of the ConanCenter recipes using components, like https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/tree/master/recipes/bitserializer/all or https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/tree/master/recipes/breakpad/all? They are well tested, maybe a bit more complicated than usual, because packaging open-source libraries is typically challenging, but could be a good starting point.